# .Net Interop.Outlook - open message from raw MIME source

Tags: .net, vb.net, outlook

I'm generating an E-Mail source like the following in my source:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="related_boundary"

--related_boundary
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>test</p>
        <p class="sig"><img src="cid:0"></p>
    </body>
</html>
--related_boundary
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <0>
....
```

Now, I want to open these mail in Outlook using Office.Interop
but setting the mail body to the named content, will only display the complete source in outlook

Comment: Are you asking how to import a MIME message in Outlook? Or just how to set the Body/HTMLBody properties?

Comment: I want to import the complete Messag

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import a complete MIME message, you can use

1 - [IConverterSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa192944(v=office.11).aspx) built-in MIME converter (Outlook 2003 and up). Since it is Extended MAPI, it is only accessible from C++ or Delphi.

2 - You can parse the MIME message explicitly in your code (I used [Lumisoft MIME parser](http://www.lumisoft.ee/lswww/download/downloads/Net/Help/html/d68af27d-67a1-8383-33e5-947ee23aa5e9.htm) in the past), then set the various properties one at a time.

3 - Use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author) and its `SafeMailItem`/[RDOMail.Import](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm) methods. Importing a new message will be as easy as

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set Msg = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items.Add("IPM.Note")
Msg.Sent = true
Msg.Import "C:\test.eml", 1024
Msg.Save
```